# Meta-Regression with BDI mean difference as a predictor?

Tags: r, metafor

I am conducting a Meta-Analysis using `metafor` in `R`.
I calculate the standardized mean difference between patient groups (PG) and healthy control groups (HC) in the self-reported utilization of rumination.

Now, I would like to conduct a Meta-Regression with the mean-difference btw. the 2 groups of each study in the BDI-II (Beck Depression Inventory II) as a predictor.

Is this possible? Meta-regression is usually conducted for study-level variables. Practically, I can calculate a BDI-Mean Difference for each study. But I think that the SD or SE also had to be considered when making such type of calculations...

My dataset has, among others, the following variables:
`n.pg` `n.hc` `bdi.pg.m` `bdi.pg.sd` `bdi.hc.m` `bdi.hc.sd` `rum.pg.m` `rum.pg.sd` `rum.hc.m` `rum.hc.sd`

Best regards

Benjamin

Comment: Because your post doesn't seem to involve coding problems, but rather a conceptual question about statistical methods, it may be more suitable for Cross Validated ([https://stats.stackexchange.com/](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Thank you! I posted it there, too!